# Open Grid Scheduler/Sun Grid Engine qrsh bad exit code on halt/reboot

Tags: exit-code, grid-computing, sungridengine

I use OGS on spot instances through qrsh calls. To have my program work properly, I need to be able to know when a job has failed due to a system shutdown (me losing the spot instance).

If we execute a remote command via ssh and the remote system goes down, the returned exit code is 255.

My problem is that with OGS, when executing a remote command with qrsh and the remote system goes down, the returned exit code is 0. 0 is meant for "ok, all good". So there is no way to know from that code that no, it's not ok and I need to reschedule.

(Of course, I could change my remote calls to return a specific code, but since it's not standard I would rather avoid that.)

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: Via an OGS qrsh call, how can I get the exit code from my program when the server goes down?